# Receiving affiliateFee in sellToken instead of buyToken

Tags: web3js, 0x, swaps

I'm currently implementing 0xRouter into my app and encountered a hurdle.

How can I deduct the fee of a trade from sellToken and not receive it in the form of buyToken? The main use for this is, if a user is buying a token via ETH. It's very inconvenient to receive the fee in tokenXY instead of ETH.

Since I don't see any way how to pass a "receiverAddress" to the callData, I tried deducting the percentage of msg.value on my relay contract directly, which then calls 0xProxy with the following parameters for the quote API call:

feeRecipient: callingUser.address,
buyTokenPercentageFee: 1

Deducting the percentage of ETH on my contract works fine, but the buyAmount becomes 50% in the calldata, which then results in 50% being sent to my relay contract and 50% being sent to my user.

I assume buyTokenPercentageFee = 1 translates to 50% which is supposed to be a safety mechanism. Looking at the tx flow I realized at _transformERC20Private() in TransformERC20Feature.sol the msg.sender becomes recipient.

In other words - there is no way of using a relay contract in front of the call to 0xProxy without having tokens sent to the relay contract?

Am I missing something? I also looked at the explicit order build etc., but also don't see a way how to achieve what I'm looking for, even if I'd go through the struggle of creating and hashing the orders myself.

I mean even uniV2 has a "to" argument for a regular swap that can be routed through a contract before being sent to the router. Looking at the highly sophisticated code of 0x it just can't be that this is not possible.